# Flag calculator in a loop While

Tags: python, while-loop, boolean, calculator, flags

I need to make a calculator in a While loop using one operand variable. Depending on the boolean variable, we enter the operator or operand only in turn, and when entering the "=" operator, we output the result of all operations and exit the loop

```
result = 0
operand = None
operator = None
wait_for_number = True
while operator != '=':
    if wait_for_number == True:
        operand = float(input('Write operand: '))
        wait_for_number = False
    if wait_for_number == False:
        operator = str(input('Write operator: '))
        if operator == '+':
            result += operand
            wait_for_number = True
        if operator == '-':
            result -= operand
            wait_for_number = True
        if operator == '/':
            result /= operand
            wait_for_number = True
        if operator == '*':
            result *= operand
            wait_for_number = True
print(result)
```

Comment: Now the question is more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few logic bugs in your code, take a look this one, and you can modify and optimize from here:

```py
result = float(input('Write operand: '))
wait_for_number = False

while True:
    if wait_for_number == False:
        operator = str(input('Write operator: '))
        if operator == '=':
            break
        wait_for_number = True

    if wait_for_number == True:
        operand = float(input('Write operand: '))
        if operator == '+':
            result += operand
        if operator == '-':
            result -= operand
        if operator == '/':
            result /= operand
        if operator == '*':
            result *= operand
        wait_for_number = False

print(result)
```